# Accessviolation with memcpy when trying to copy from and to managed memory passed as IntPtr

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, access-violation, memcpy

I'm trying to simply copy one buffer to another buffer by passing two pointers to a C++ Function which is by called by C#-Code.

Also tried:

```cs
[DllImport(dllName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern IntPtr ConvertYUV420pToRGB24(byte[] src, byte[] dst);
```

The C++-Function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) uint8_t* __stdcall ConvertYUV420pToRGB24(uint8_t* src, uint8_t* dst) {
    errno_t err;

    err = memcpy_s(dst, 3110400, src, 3110400);

    if (err)
        return NULL;
    else
        return dst;
}
```

The DLLImport

```
[DllImport(dllName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern IntPtr ConvertYUV420pToRGB24(IntPtr src, IntPtr dst);
```

The calling C# code

```
GCHandle srcPtr;
GCHandle dstPtr;

byte[] result = new byte[3110400];
byte[] srcFrame = new byte[3110400];


srcPtr = GCHandle.Alloc(srcFrame);
dstPtr = GCHandle.Alloc(result);

FFmpegInterface.ConvertYUV420pToRGB24(GCHandle.ToIntPtr(srcPtr), GCHandle.ToIntPtr(dstPtr));
```

Result: Access-Violation

Expected: Just copy

Comment: `public static extern IntPtr ConvertYUV420pToRGB24(byte[] src, byte[] dst);` will be fine, just pass the two byte arrays, suitably allocated to the correct length, and let the framework pin them.

Comment: You can pass the array themselves.

Comment: pls see below answer

Comment: No really, it can be done that way. Your actual code must have a defect somewhere.

Comment: Sine memory got freeed in DLLMain with DLL_THREAD_DETACH and this was somehow called, the heap got broken. So the real problem seems to be caused by this.

Comment: I guess you should remove the question in that case

Comment: the whole thing? i would let it stay, so people can see how to you DLLImport with Pointers. For the DLL_THREAD_DETACH, seems like it gets called when the Visual Studio Debugger runs into a breakpoint somewhere.